# Loop through ASP.NET DataList with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can we loop through all ASP.NET DataList item's and access the value of all item's in the ItemTemplate (In this case, the checkbox and the label) with Javascript ?

Here's the asp.net :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataGroup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DataKeyField="GroupName" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server"/>
          <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupName") %>' style="padding-right:30px;"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I am not sure if I should use Jquery or just pure Javascript...

Comment: First you'll need to examine the *client-side* markup of your document.  JavaScript has no knowledge of what a `asp:DataList` is, or any of the other server-side elements shown here.  JavaScript would be targeting the client-side HTML elements.  With those you can use any jQuery selector to identify them.

Comment: Added ClientIDMode="static", so the id of the list will be "DataGroup"

Comment: That's a good start, you can *probably* select *some* element as `$('#DataGroup')` (assuming the ID is unique in the DOM).  But, again, you need to examine your client-side markup in order to be more specific.  JavaScript can't target server-side controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to every item in the list like below

```
  <asp:DataList ID="DataGroup" runat="server" DataKeyField="GroupName" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1"  Class ="dataGroupItem" runat="server"/>
              <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" Class ="dataGroupItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupName")  %>' style="padding-right:30px;"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Then just loop through everything with that class name like this:

```
<script>
    $('.dataGroupItem').each(function(){
        //Todo
    });
</script>
```

Here is a link to jsFiddle so you can try it out with an Count: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4vvf/)

Answer (score 0):

Compile your files and run in a browser. 
Right-click and select "view source".
Locate your checkbox (it will be an input in HTML but the id should be the same.*
insert script tags just before the closing body tag in your ASPX file and run this script

Something like this (not tested)

```
<script>
var chkBox = document.getElementById("chk1");
if (chkBox.checked)
{
    doSomething();
}
</script>
```

*EDIT: The id might have changed to somthing like "ContentPlaceHolder1_chk1"